# How to properly echo PHP variables within JS script?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have this script that needs to print and it is within a PHP file as I need to pass it options because I am using the jQuery UI Tabs plugin.

Here is what I have:

```
<?php 
$collapsible = "true";
$active = "2";

$options = array( 'collapsible' => $collapsible, 'active' => $active );
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery( '.tabs' ).tabs({
                collapsible : <?php echo $options["collapsible"]; ?>,
                active : <?php echo $options["active"]; ?>
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Ok so everything works however the two options collapsible and active isn't effecting it.  But if I bypass the php variables and just hardcode the option settings in for collapsible and active, then it works.  So I am not sure why the variables have no effect.  I've even tried type casting it with (int) for active and (bool) for collapsible but still no dice.

Thanks for looking.

Comment: use single quota '<?php echo $options["collapsible"] ); ?>'

Comment: if what you need is a "true/false", then you might want to change that, because php will echo 1 or 0 respectively.

Comment: Don't build JavaScript using server-side languages. HTML belongs in .html files, CSS belongs in .css files, and JS belongs in .js files. If you need to relate server-side data with specific elements, [use `[data-*]` attributes](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes). You're obviously using jQuery, so [you can take advantage of the `.data()` method as well](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261619/jquery-data-vs-attr/7262427#7262427).

Comment: zzzzBov - i don't think i have choice in this case as this is a shortcode within wordpress which means user has control of the options for the jquery tabs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than adding quotes, run the value through `json_encode`. This will ensure proper escaping as well:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery( '.tabs' ).tabs({
            collapsible : <?php echo json_encode($options["collapsible"]) ?>,
            active : <?php echo json_encode($options["active"]) ?>'
        });
    });
</script>
```

It also gives you the added benefit of being able to use literal types as opposed to all strings in your PHP:

```
<?php
$collapsible = true;
$active = 2;
```

And, per axel.michel suggestion in comments, could be simplified to:

```
<?php
$options = array('collapsible' => true, 'active' => 2);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery( '.tabs' ).tabs(<?php echo json_encode($options); ?>);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It could be simlyfied by using the complete array: <?php $options = array( 'collapsible' => true, 'active' => 2 );
?>
jQuery( '.tabs' ).tabs(<?php echo json_encode($options); ?>);

Answer (score 0):

Try adding quotes around the values and encode the output

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery( '.tabs' ).tabs({
            collapsible : '<?php echo $options["collapsible"] ); ?>',
            active : '<?php echo $options["active"] ); ?>'
        });
    });
</script>
```